# How to bind an ABSOLUTE path instead of relative to a subscript which uses Node and Perl calls in it?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, bash, shell

I have a script which has a code like this:

```
def tokenize(latex,kind='normalize'):
    output_file = './out.lst'
    input_file = './input_file.lst'

    cmd = "perl -pe 's|hskip(.*?)(cm\\|in\\|pt\\|mm\\|em)|hspace{\\1\\2}|g' %s > %s"%(input_file, output_file)
    ret = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

    temp_file = output_file + '.tmp' # Create Temporary file
    with open(temp_file, 'w') as fout:  
        with open(output_file) as fin:
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line.replace('\r', ' ').strip() + '\n')  # delete \r

    cmd = "cat %s | node ./preprocess_latex.js %s > %s "%(temp_file, kind, output_file)
    ret = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    os.remove(temp_file)
```

This `tokenize` function is is in:
`main -> latex -> scripts -> preprocessing -> utils.py -> tokenize()`
and it uses a file named `preprocess_latex.js` which is in the same directory. I have `__init__.py` files in every directory so that I can call the `tokenize()` from the main as:

```
from latex_utils.scripts.preprocessing.filter_tokenize import *
```

**Problem: I can not change directory structure nor I can move `preprocess.js`** as it uses some [KaTex](https://katex.org/) with some complex JavaScript (which I have no idea what it is and what it does) and calls some files from `../../some_file/some_script.js`

The error is this:

```
>>> from latex_utils.scripts.preprocessing.filter_tokenize import *
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/admin1/Desktop/Work/Search Improve/Latex/latex_simialarity/preprocess_latex.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
None
```

But When I call the script inside `main/latex_utils/scripts/preprocessing` as:

```
from filter_tokenize import *
```

it runs perfectly fine. Problem is this relative path in the line

```
cmd = "cat %s | node ./preprocess_latex.js %s > %s "%(temp_file, kind, output_file)
```

and I don't know what to. Can someone please help?

[See Line 68 of this original Repo and code](https://github.com/harvardnlp/im2markup/blob/master/scripts/preprocessing/preprocess_formulas.py)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your JS code in https://github.com/harvardnlp/im2markup/blob/master/scripts/preprocessing/preprocess_latex.js uses relative paths, so once you moved it to a different folder you will see the error.

If you just want to move the file you need to change the relative paths, e.g.  `require("../../third_party/katex/katex.js")` ->  `require("../third_party/katex/katex.js")` if you moved it one level up.

Comment: No, this is the problem, I can not do that as there are a huge number of files correlated to each other and I have to change all of those if I change one.

Comment: I believe that you should not change all of them if you change the entry point. Because Node.js will resolve the relative paths of the modules you require relative to their location so if you move the file `preprocess_latex.js` and change its `require` you don't need to change `require` inside `katex.js`;

Comment: Thank you. I got your point and I did that. My point is that everytime I'll `import` the `tokenize`, I'll have to give the path of the `preprocess_latex.js` file too or I'll have to call the function in its own directory. I want to how can I get the **relative path of the executing script `filter.py` so that it can automatically gets its path**?

Comment: Well, you may try to add a global variable that will calc the absolute path to the `preprocess_latex.js` on the init, and then whenever you need it to use the variable. Now you will need to update the path once in the variable declaration.

Comment: For now, I have just used an argument `js_file_path` but hat is just a patch. I want to put all these scripts in the same directory and call  `tokenize` from anywhere.